# Server's key not work in Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a project in Firebase Cloud Messaging and today my server key stopped work, so I had to change it and it earned. So I have a question: how long time server key is alive in Firebase?

Comment: How do you know the problem is with the server key?

Comment: @doug-stevenson, I create new app in Firebase and change key and app id in my project